# Close modal only after API finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, modal-dialog

I am learning `ReactJS`.
I am showing a popup-modal to add a new account in account list through API call.

```
{newExpendixAccount && (
            <ConfirmDialog
              title="Create New Expendix Account"
              children={<ModalContent action="new" />}
              open={newExpendixAccount}
              setOpen={setNewExpendixAccount}
              onConfirm={newAccount}
              isLoading={false}
              onClose={() => {}}
            />
          )}
```

As you see in above code if `newExpendixAccount === true` then it will show a modal-popup like given in below image :

[image]

Now If I write something in input and press YES button then `onConfirm={newAccount}` will run.

Given below is the `newAccount` function :

```
  const newAccount = () => {
    const data = {
      PKID: 0,
      AccountName: accountInputValue.username,
    };
    createOrUpdateAccount(data, (res) => { // calling API and getting response
      if (res?.data?.Success === true && res?.status === 200) {
        NotificationManager.success(res?.data?.ErrorMessage);
        setAccountData((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          usersAccountData: [...prevState.usersAccountData, res.data.Model],
        }));
        return true;
      } else {
        NotificationManager.error(res.message || res?.data?.ErrorMessage);
        return false;
      }
    });
  };
```

Given below is the `ConfirmDialog` component :

```
const ConfirmDialog = ({
  title,
  children,
  open,
  setOpen,
  onConfirm,
  isLoading,
  onClose,
}) => {
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      aria-labelledby='confirm-dialog'
    >
      <DialogTitle id='confirm-dialog'>{title}</DialogTitle>
      {isLoading && <LinearProgress></LinearProgress>}
      <DialogContent>{children}</DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(false);
            onClose();
          }}
          color='secondary'
        >
          No
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(false);
            onConfirm();
          }}
          disabled={isLoading}
          color='primary'
        >
          Yes
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
export default ConfirmDialog;
```

Please take a look on method `onClick` of `YES button` :

```
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(false);
            onConfirm();
          }}
          disabled={isLoading}
          color='primary'
        >
          Yes
        </Button>
```

### The problem is in `onClick` function.

Whenever I press `YES` button, it first closes the modal pop-up by running  `setOpen(false)` and then it calls the API function `onConfirm()` which I sent as prop.

**I want** to close pop-up modal only after API request finishes.
How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update you function to accept a function that will call it once the api call is done.

```
  const newAccount = (onFinish = () => {}) => {
    const data = {
      PKID: 0,
      AccountName: accountInputValue.username,
    };
    createOrUpdateAccount(data, (res) => { // calling API and getting response
      if (res?.data?.Success === true && res?.status === 200) {
        NotificationManager.success(res?.data?.ErrorMessage);
        setAccountData((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          usersAccountData: [...prevState.usersAccountData, res.data.Model],
        }));
        return true;
      } else {
        NotificationManager.error(res.message || res?.data?.ErrorMessage);
        return false;
      }
      onFinish();
    });
  };
```

then do:

```
onClick={() => {
    onConfirm(() => {setOpen(false)});
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! . Problem is resolved.  But I am using as `onConfirm(setLoader, setOpen);` . I am sending both loader and modal open local states.

Comment: Can you please post second  answer by using `async-await` ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach I can think of is, you make the onClick() function as async, and await on onConfirm() to finish (for this you need to modify your newAccount() to return a promise which will resolve once the API call is completed)

```
//this is how it should look like
onClick = {
  async () => {
    await onConfirm();
    setOpen(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: this wont work because the onConfirm is not returning a Promise

Comment: @walidsahli please read my answer again, I specifically mentioned that you need to modify newAccount() to return a promise.

Comment: @RishabhGour your answer make sense..  needs to modify newAccoint() to return promise and change onClick behavior

Comment: sorry yes that way it will work for sure

Comment: Can you write `newAccount` which will return a promise? Please write full answer. I want to understand.